# Why does my CAPTCHA image not show with certain browsers/SSL configurations

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Okay on our public site:
https://www.midwestiso.org/Pages/Login.aspx

When you click the Forgot Password link, sometimes with some browsers people can't see the CAPTCHA image.

The image is an inline, BASE64 encoded PNG graphic.

The problem seems to be around SSL connections, but I can't figure out why.

When the error happens, it gives that message about showing both secure and unsecure content.

The user then gets the litte Red X instead of my picture.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Inline images using Data URI (data:) is only supported by up to date browsers. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) this currently is:

> As of March 2012, Data URIs are supported by the following web browsers:
>    - Gecko-based, such as Firefox, SeaMonkey, XeroBank, Camino, Fennec and K-Meleon
>    - Konqueror, via KDE's KIO slaves input/output system
>    - Opera (including devices such as the Nintendo DSi or Wii)
>    - WebKit-based, such as Safari (including on iOS), Android's browser, Kindle 4's browser, Epiphany and Midori (WebKit is a derivative of Konqueror's KHTML engine, but Mac OS X does not share the KIO architecture so the implementations are different), and Webkit/Chromium-based, such as Chrome
>   -  Trident
>   -  - Internet Explorer 8: Microsoft has limited its support to certain "non-navigable" content for security reasons, including concerns that JavaScript embedded in a data URI may not be interpretable by script filters such as those used> by web-based email clients. Data URIs must be smaller than 32 KiB in Version 8. Data URIs are supported only for the following elements and/or attributes:
>   -  -  - object (images only)
>   -  -  - img
>   -  -  - input type=image
>   -  -  - link (data URI must be base64 encoded)
>   -  -  - CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background-image, background, list-style-type, list-style and similar.
>   -  Internet Explorer 9: Internet Explorer 9 does not have 32KiB limitation and allowed in broader elements.

Comment: Awesome, that's it. I made a boo boo. Does anybody know of another dynamic image display techlonogy?